# Display String and Int Array at once

Tags: java

I am not sure how to display a string and int array at the same time so that it will display the maximum value of the array with the specific month

```
Global:
static double[] set2014 = new double[6];
static String[] months = new String[6];
```

Here is the method for calculating the maximum value:

```
public static void max(){
    initialise();
    double max = set2014[0];

    for(int i = 1; i < set2014.length; i++){
        if(set2014[i] > max){
            max = set2014[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("------------------");
    System.out.println("Largest figure is " + max);
}
```

For example, the output will be:
Largest figure is: 
March 204566

Comment: Where does month come in to this? Is it the index into the `set2014` array?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. For instance, you mention, "with the specific month" -- but *what* month? There's no month in your code, and the rest of the question is a bit vague to me. Please consider adding more pertinent detail and code to help us understand your problem, your code, and your question.

Comment: Understand please that the only window that we have on what your program is doing, what your trying to achieve or what your problem is, is what you tell and show us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maintaining two arrays that are linked by index is what I call Object Denial. Consider creating a class that contains both month and value.

```
public interface MonthValue { //class or interface, I just didn't want to type out the simple implementation
   String getMonth();
   double getDouble();
}

//set2014 now needs to contain MonthValues
MonthValue max = set2014[0];

for(int i = 1; i < set2014.length; i++){
    MonthValue current = set2014[i];
    if(current.getValue() > max.getValue()){
        max = current;
    }
}

System.out.println("Largest figure is " + max.getValue());
System.out.println("In month " + max.getMonth());
```

But to answer your question as is:

You can keep track of the index instead:

```
int maxMonthIndex = 0;

for(int i = 1; i < set2014.length; i++){
    if(set2014[i] > set2014[maxMonthIndex]){
        maxMonthIndex = i;
    }
}

System.out.println("Largest figure is " + set2014[maxMonthIndex]);
System.out.println("In month " + months[maxMonthIndex]);
```

By the way, `set` is a bad name for an array. Sets are unordered collections, arrays have an order.